# ReactJS- image src call to another folder error

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, webpack

This is what it looks like

```
<img className='imgclass' src={"../" + require(aLc.value)} alt='' key={aLc.value} />
```

I need to make path like `../m/b/image.jpg`, while `aLc.value` contain path `/m/b/image.jpg` so i need to add only `..` bafore path folder, but it did not work. I tried to do like in example above, but it gives me error `Error: Cannot find module '/m/b/image.jpg'`. I tried to do

```
<img className='imgclass' src={require(".." + aLc.value)} alt='' key={aLc.value} />
```

But this gives me error `Error: Cannot find module "."`

How can I fix that?

@edit - Map function - SOLVED

```
const ProductsList = ({ data: {loading, error, allLinks }}) => {
  if (loading) {
    return <p>Loading ...</p>;
  }
  if (error) {
    return <p>{error.message}</p>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="productList">
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
        {
            allLinks.items.map( aL =>
            <div key={aL.id} className="product">

            {
                aL.custom_attributes.map( aLc =>

                    aLc.__typename === 'CustomString' && aLc.attribute_code === 'image'

                        ? <img className='imgclass'  src={require(`../components${aLc.value}`} alt='' key={aLc.value} />  //without subordinate folder 'components' react auto delete one of dots e.g (require(`..${aLc.value}`) => Error: Cannot find module '.' because react deleted one dot.
                    :  aLc.__typename === 'CustomString' && aLc.attribute_code === 'description'
                        ? <div key={aL.id}>{aLc.value}</div>
                    :  aLc.__typename === 'CustomArray'
                        ?   aLc.aliasVar.map( aV => <div key={aV}>{aV}</div>)
                    : null


                )

            }
            </div> )
        }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

`allLinks` is the type name of api. All values exist in api.

Comment: use template strings once, Ex : const myImg = './cute.jpg';

<img src={require(`${myImg}`)} />

Comment: This could be usefull, but not here unfortunately. The aLc.value is mapped in function in which I cannot add variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write :

```
<img className='imgclass' src={`../${aLc.value}`} alt='' key={aLc.value} />
```

It would work hopefully.

Comment: Without require in path it cannot render image (when I added border to css, it is on page but with size 0x0). Tried `src={require('..${aLc.value}')` but gives `Error: Cannot find module "."`.

Comment: Either you aLc.value might empty string. Print the path before require. Might Guide you

Comment: It's not empy. I checked it before. Like I said above, `aLc.value` = `/m/b/image.jpg`. I don't know what cause this errors. If I add full path without `aLc.value` (`"../m/b/image.jpg"`) in require() it render it properly.

Comment: if it's not empty store like var img = require(aLc.value);, if var img is loaded, do like  {back-ticks`..${img}`back-ticks} this will print "../m/b/image.jpg".

Comment: I cant use variables here, this images is render in map function and aLc.value is also mapped in this function. If I create `var img =  require(aLc.value)` outside map function it will say that `aLc.value` is undefined.

Comment: Can we have any fiddle or sandbox for it? 
or some more piece of code so that we can have understanding of scopes of functions more?

Comment: Added. Feel free to look at it.

Comment: I guess ```<img className='imgclass' src={`../${aLc.value}`} alt='' key={aLc.value} />```
 It would work if aLc.value exists.

Did you try to print aLc.value ?

Comment: Like I said before. It exist. `allLinks` is the type name of api and inside function api is mapped.

Comment: `../${aLc.value}` 
What is the output for this ?

Comment: Output: `../m/b/image.jpg`. But without `require()` in src path it cant be rendered on page, because webpack needs `require()`.
https://medium.com/@kathleeng.lopez/rendering-local-images-with-react-and-webpack-5f9d1fdb9b54

Comment: What is happening when you do ```require(`../${aLc.value}`)``` .

Comment: Output: `Error: Cannot find module './/m/b/image.jpg'.` After delete extra / `Error: Cannot find module '.'`

Comment: Okay, it seems like if I add two dots as string before `aLc.value` react is auto deleting one of dots, thats why i was getting error `cannot find module '.'`. After I moved it to subordinate folder not in source folder I managed to render it on page. Unfortunatelly this is not what i wanted, but there isn't other way and now I must rebuild my folder structure :/ Anyway... thanks for help :)